# Vue template to render function generation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue template in a gwt app (vuegwt-plugin). 
My Problem is I use a third party lib from vuejs ecosystem and my template uses this plugin. I want generate render function based from this template.
I have used this online generator: https://vuejs-tips.github.io/compile.

This generator outputs functions like this:

```js
   _c(
                                'span', [
                                    _v(
                                        _s(
                                            entry
                                            .name
                                        )
                                    )
                                ]
                            )
                        ]) : _e(),
                        _l((
```

I assume _c is the createElement parameter to render(createElement) function.

But what is _v(), _s() , _e() etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Your link points to a 404, but from what I can tell those functions are vue internal methods defined [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/4d4d22a3f6017c46d08b67afe46af43027b06629/src/core/instance/render-helpers/index.js) and [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/8a800867fe61e5aa642e1e3da91bb890d07312f7/src/core/instance/render.js#L31) which are not really meant for public usage.

You may also check the [component flow types](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/52719ccab8fccffbdf497b96d3731dc86f04c1ce/flow/component.js#L95).